# Chop floats from useless zeroes julia

Tags: julia

I saw [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Strings_and_characters) that julia has some `%f` style in printing the floats.
I would like to know if this is possible to do it in setting the name of some output file. I mean that in my program I have something like:

```
...
for epsilon in epsilon_array
    ...
    printfile = open("outputfile_epsilon$(epsilon).dat", "w")
    ...
end
...
```

So for instance, if I have `epsilon=0.010000000` (float64), I want that the name of the outputfile is just `outputfile_epsilon0.1.dat`

EDIT:

For example consider the following "filling" of my the array:

```
epsilon_array = zeros(Float64,100)
iijj = 0.0
for ii in 1:100
    epsilon_array[ii] = iijj
    iijj += 0.01
end
```

If I take a look at some outputfile, I will have:

```
outputfile_epsilon0.9500000000000006.dat
```

So the problem is that there's a nasty number at the end of the float, that forces julia to print the whole integer.

Comment: Maybe this post would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031133/how-do-you-format-a-string-when-interpolated-in-julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rstrip()` function which will remove instances of a given character from the right side of a string (see documentation [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/strings/)).  E.g.

```
epsilon=0.010000000
eps_String = rstrip("$epsilon", '0')
println(eps_String)
# 0.01
```

**edit:** I'm not certain that any kind of formatting is actually necessary here though.  If your numbers are indeed stored as floats, then trailing zeros shouldn't be stored with them.  E.g. even without the `rstrip()` in the example above I get:

```
julia> epsilon_array = [0.010000000, 0.02000000]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.01
 0.02    

julia> for epsilon in epsilon_array
           println("outputfile_epsilon$(epsilon).dat")
       end
outputfile_epsilon0.01.dat
outputfile_epsilon0.02.dat
```

Comment: I am unmarking the question because the bug that I have. I added some edit to put on comparison why I was asking for trimming zeroes.

Comment: @user2820579 In that case, what about just rounding the number `round( )`, (you can specify the number of decimal precision you need) and then applying the above technique?

Comment: It's true, I just did instead 25/100 for instance and I am getting the required float. I think that would be qualified as a minor bug, perhaps..

Answer (score 4):

The crux of the problem here seems to be that you are not accounting for roundoff error in your summation. Float64 can't represent 0.01 exactly, so computers instead store the closest approximation. Each time you use epsilon in a computation, you increase the resulting error. The range and linspace functions are aware of this, and are thus able to avoid the problem:

```
iijj = 0:0.01:1
for ii in 1:100
    epsilon_array[ii] = iijj[ii]
end
```

Alternatively, you might decide that you just always really want 2 digits printed, in which case you could use printf-style formatting for the filename:

```
open(@sprintf("outputfile_epsilon%.2f.dat", epsilon), "w")
```