# Is there a way to stop Julia using scientific (exponential) notation with BigFloats?

Tags: julia, scientific-notation, bigfloat

OK, I have what seems to be, on the face of it, a simple problem. I want to take the decimal part of an irrational number up to a specified number of digits and treat that as an integer. For example, if my irrational number is 2.657829... and I want five digits, I'm looking for 65782 (though I'm actually dealing with 'Big' numbers).

This is easily achieved using strings, for example if I wanted the decimal part of root 3 to 50 digits:

```
function main_1(n::Int, m::Int)::BigInt
    setprecision(Int(trunc((m + 3) * log2(10))))
    sr = string(sqrt(big(n)))
    ff = findfirst(sr, '.')
    dp = parse(BigInt, sr[ff + 1:ff + m])
    return dp
end

@time main_1(3, 50)
```

The output is `73205080756887729352744634150587236694280525381038`.

However, I resent using strings when I'm dealing solely with numbers! What I want to be able to do is start with a BigFloat, subtract the integer part, multiply the result by the appropriate factor of 10, round the result to zero, and then convert it to a BigInt. The problem is that Julia uses scientific / exponential notation, so I don't seem to be able to achieve what I want using only numbers. The following (partial) code shows the problem:

```
function main_2(n::Int, m::Int)::BigFloat
    setprecision(Int(trunc((m + 3) * log2(10))))
    sr = sqrt(big(n))
    tr = trunc(sr)
    dp = (sr - tr) * big(10.0) ^ 50
    return dp
end

@time main_2(3, 50)
```

The output in this case is `7.32050807568877293527446341505872366942805253810380625e+49` (there's a few extra digits that would have been removed at the rounding stage).

So my question is, is there any way to achieve my objective without resorting to strings?

Comment: Use `@sprintf` as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031535/3637404

Comment: I say "without resorting to strings" and you give me a string? Yeah, I could replace `return dp` in the code above with `return parse(BigInt, @sprintf("%.0f", dp))` (and change the function type from BigFloat to BigInt), but it actually doubles the run-time from my own string method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achive this, without using strings, is to convert the result and it's integer part to *BigInt* before do the subtract (and change the function type from *BigFloat* to *BigInt*):

```
function main_2(n::Int, m::Int)::BigInt
    setprecision(Int(trunc((m + 3) * log2(10))))

    # Calc the sqrt
    result = sqrt(big(n))

    # Convert the whole number to BigInt to the specified precision
    sr = convert(BigInt, trunc(result*big(10)^m))

    # Convert the integer part to BigInt
    tr = convert(BigInt, trunc(result)*big(10)^m)

    dp = sr - tr
    return dp
end
```

Comparing the above implementation with the `main_1` function, there is a little improvement:

```
julia> @time main_1(3, 50)
  0.000042 seconds (36 allocations: 5.254 KiB)
73205080756887729352744634150587236694280525381038

julia> @time main_2(3, 50)
  0.000028 seconds (51 allocations: 1.617 KiB)
73205080756887729352744634150587236694280525381038
```

---

**Edit:**

Other way (as commented by @Bill) is just *trunc* the result (to get rid of `InexactError()`) and change the function type to *BigInt*:

```
function main_2(n::Int, m::Int)::BigInt
    setprecision(Int(trunc((m + 3) * log2(10))))
    sr = sqrt(big(n))
    tr = trunc(sr)
    dp = (sr - tr) * big(10.0) ^ 50
    return trunc(dp)
end
```

After testing:

```
julia> @time main_2(3,50)
  0.000026 seconds (28 allocations: 1.016 KiB)
73205080756887729352744634150587236694280525381038
```

Comment: Yes, return BigInt not BigFloat to get rid of the exponential formatting of the answer.

Comment: Both those methods are helpful, thanks. With regard to the second method, I didn't realise that changing the function type to `BigInt` would result in an automatic conversion of `BigFloat`, I just assumed it would trigger an error message. So you learn something every day...